Unable to read external flash with FATFS. STM32
I am using stm32L4 microcontroller and I have connected my board with an external flash (AT45DB041E), which I have successfully managed to communicate with the it using the SPI peripheral. All I want to do is to find a binary file that exists in the external flash in a specific path "fs/update.bin". For that reason I use FATFS. However, I am not able to mount the external flash. Maybe I am not using it properly. This is my code for mounting the external flash and trying to see if the file exists in the flash memory. Every time I am getting FR_NOT_READY status. I use 3.6V in a custom board and I can read the manufacturer ID of the flash, so the connections are ok.
Is this the proper way to do what I have described above?
FATFS *fs;
FIL fil;

FRESULT err = FR_NOT_READY;

fs = malloc(sizeof(FATFS));

/*Initialize the external flash memory*/
at45db_init();

HAL_Delay(2);

/*Enable the device*/
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

err = f_mount(fs, "fs", 1);
if (err == FR_OK) {
  printf("Mounted successfully\n\r");
} else {
  printf("Error in mounting external flash memory\n\r");
}

err = f_open(&fil, "/fs/update.bin", FA_OPEN_EXISTING);
if (err == FR_OK) {
  printf("The file exists in flash memory\n\r");
} else {
  printf("The file does not exists in flash memory\n\r");
}


Are you sure your flash already has a valid FAT FS? Can you verify the file allocation table is there? Can you use a microcontroller to dump raw binary data from it?

@Ilya Yes, I have another project that manages to write the binary file inside the flash, however it uses the littlefs with mbed. So everything is there but I am unable to mount the flash into my new project with the FATFS. Could be th3 3.5V a problem?

No, voltage has nothing to do with it. You didn't answer if you can read things back when you write them. On the other note, did you just say you wrote files as LittleFS? If that's the case, you won't be able to read anything as FATFS. It's the same as writing files on NTFS disk on Windows and then trying to read it as APFS on Mac. Different file systems have different byte-level layout in the storage. They're simply incompatible.

@Ilya So you are saying that in order to read the file from the external flash I have to use littlefs in my project as the project that writes the binary file inside the flash with the use of mbed?

Yes. You can read only with the same file system that writes the data. All file systems do completely different things to data on a raw byte level. LittleFS stores file metadata one way, FATFS does it another way, NTFS does it in yet another way and so on. They can't interpret data structures of each other.

@Ilya Thank you very much I haven't use this kind of library yet and I am trying to understand how to use it. However, thanks a lot for clearing things up in my mind.

@Ilya May I ask one more question? Could be possible to read the file that is stored in the external flash without any littlefs library, but with the local functions, which are in the datasheet of the external flash?

What exactly is a local function in a datasheet? Those functions need to exist somewhere in code. I presume those functions are something like ReadDataAt(offset, length). So they probably only read raw data, file system is an abstraction on top of it. What you need is to interpret data in the flash as a file system. In other words, files written with LittleFS need to be read using LittleFS, otherwise you need to do raw data forensics on that flash, and it's definitely not something you intend to do. So in short, no. You need to use the same file system for writes and reads.

You use LittleFS to write data to Flash, but you try to read that data using FAT. This won't work, because different file systems use different data structures to store file metadata and data locations on a disk (pointers to file contents).
Every file system uses different data structures to keep track of memory blocks and files, they can have different flags and properties assigned to files, and they are stored in a way unique to that file system. FAT file system driver will simply fail to interpret data structures of LittleFS as a valid FAT file system.
This is why you can't open a storage managed by LittleFS as FAT, this is why you can't read a Mac APFS disk as a Windows NTFS disk - the bytes in the same physical locations have different meanings for them.
A storage area should be managed only by a single file system. You either write and read it all with FAT, or you write and read it all with LittleFS.
